# jQuery UI Droppable - How to allow only 1 element per drop zone, instead of stacking

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, droppable

My current script: https://jsfiddle.net/uoyp37bj/11/

The issue is that currently it's possible to "stack" droppable elements by dragging them on-top of each other. I'm trying to make it so that only the latest dropped element stays there, and any previous elements are removed.

I originally just "hid" the additional items using CSS, but as I'm using an input box to keep track of which items exist in the drop zones, this is no longer possible. Any help would be really appreciated, hoping it's something relatively simple within the jQuery UI API, but currently nothing has worked for me.

```
$(".social-msl-link-label").draggable({
  connectToSortable: ".social-msl-group-list",
  revert: "invalid",
  helper: "clone"
});

var orderMSLids = [];
var droppableOptions = {
  accept: ".social-msl-link-label",
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  greedy: true,
  hoverClass: 'highlight',
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    orderMSLids = [];
    $(ui.draggable).clone(true).detach().css({
      position: 'relative',
      top: 'auto',
      left: 'auto'
    }).appendTo(this);

    orderMSLids.push($(this).find('.social-msl-link-label').attr('id'));

    $(this).siblings().filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().trim() === $(ui.draggable).text().trim();
    }).empty();

    str = [];
    $(".social-msl-links-order li").each(function(index) {
      var res = $(this).children().attr('id');
      if (res) {
        str.push(res);
      }
    });

    var string = str.join(",");
    $('#msl-order').val(string);


  }
};

$(".social-msl-links-order li.social-msl-drop").droppable(droppableOptions);

$('.social-msl-add').click(function() {
  var $droppable = $('<li class="social-msl-drop"></li>').droppable(droppableOptions);
  $droppable.insertBefore('.social-msl-add');
});

$('#msl-order').prop('value').split(',').forEach(function(id) {
  var $droppable = $('.social-msl-drop.ui-droppable:empty').first();
  if (id) {
    $('.draggable #' + id).clone(true).appendTo($droppable);
  }
});
```

Just had a thought, but haven't progressed - may be possible to iterate over all of the elements inside the "drop" call, and remove any duplicates. Within this loop, could also check if any drop zones have 2 elements and remove all except 1. Not sure how to script that, but the initial logic makes sense to me.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cjL39f6y/ Try something like this one

Comment: @RLam thanks, really appreciate that - definitely understand how that works, what I'd like it to be able to do is "replace" whatever you drop. So if you drop Link1 onto of Link2, Link2 is removed and only Link1 remains.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z2t0r59c/ Check this. What I do is assign a variable for your clone element, and using it to remove the other draggable element when the user is dragging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of appending the draggable to droppable, just replace it's entire content with the draggable like this:

```
$(this).html(ui.draggable.clone(true).css({
  position: 'relative',
  top: 'auto',
  left: 'auto'
}));
```

Instead of:

```
 $(ui.draggable).clone(true).detach().css({
  position: 'relative',
  top: 'auto',
  left: 'auto'
}).appendTo(this);
```

Comment: Perfect! Makes so much sense, definitely the cleanest solution - thank you!